# Proving "If $P$ and $Q$ then $R$".

Tags: logic

1. I want to prove the statement: If $P$ and $Q$ then $R$.
   I have proved the statement: If $P$ then $R$.
   I am done.  Right?
2. I want to prove the statement: If $P$ or $Q$ then $R$.
   I have proved the statement: If $P$ then $R$.
   I am NOT done.  I must also prove the statement: If $Q$ then $R$.  Right?

Comment: Right ${}\times 2$ (now $\ddot{\smile}$).

Comment: You have a typo in Question #2: The second "If P then R." should be "If Q then R."

Comment: Yes Thank you.  The typo is corrected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion is correct. In symbols you can write it as
$$P \Rightarrow R \implies (P\wedge Q) \Rightarrow R$$
But
$$P \Rightarrow R\ \ \not\!\!\!\implies (P \vee Q) \Rightarrow R$$
Since $P \impliedby P \wedge Q$ but $P\ \ \ \not\!\!\!\!\impliedby P \vee Q$.
And finally
$$P \Rightarrow R \wedge Q \Rightarrow R \implies (P \vee Q) \Rightarrow R$$
We can even say that
$$P \Rightarrow R \wedge Q \Rightarrow R \iff (P \vee Q) \Rightarrow R$$
but not
$$P \Rightarrow R \impliedby (P\wedge Q) \Rightarrow R$$